# MSBuild fails to build x64 executable

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have a C++ project that I am building with Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows Desktop.  I can build it in the IDE for Debug | x64 with no problem.

I want to build it directly with MSBuild from the command line so I call:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
>
> msbuild \LedaAP.sln /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:PreferredToolArchitecture=x64 /p:useenv=true /flp:logfile=LedaAp.log;verbosity=normal

Linkage fails:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\Jenkins\workspace\LedaAP_VisualStudio\software\Source\LedaAP\x64\Debug\LedaAP.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO ws2_32.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /Debug /PDB:"C:\Jenkins\workspace\LedaAP_VisualStudio\software\Source\LedaAP\x64\Debug\LedaAP.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:\Jenkins\workspace\LedaAP_VisualStudio\software\Source\LedaAP\x64\Debug\LedaAP.lib" /MACHINE:X64 x64\Debug\Configuration.obj
>
> x64\Debug\Configuration.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' [C:\Jenkins\workspace\LedaAP_VisualStudio\software\Source\LedaAP\LedaAP.vcxproj]
> 12:15:05 Done Building Project "C:\Jenkins\workspace\LedaAP_VisualStudio\software\Source\LedaAP\LedaAP.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
> 12:15:05 Done Building Project "C:\Jenkins\workspace\LedaAP_VisualStudio\software\Source\LedaAP\LedaAP.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
> Build FAILED.

I guess the failure is because the linker is called with multiple 32-bit libraries but I am not explicitly specifying those in the project's property pages.

Any ideas how to fix this please?

Comment: Use "vcvarall.bat x64" and try again.

Comment: I only have: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

Comment: x64 is an *argument* to vcvarsall.bat.  It tells the .bat file to setup the build environment to produce x64 executables.  Right now, with no argument, you get an x86 build environment.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I understand now. But with that argument I get: **"The specified configuration type is missing.  The tools for the configuration might not be installed."** So I'll have to work out how to get them.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans suggested the answer was to call:

vcvarsall.bat x64

but I also had to uninstall 'Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows Desktop' and install 'Visual C++ Build Tools' from:

http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

to get the 64-bit tools.